# Power Query: Concatenate All Rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am looking to concatenate rows instead of columns. I can do this by pivoting and merging columns, but that process is not repeatable as the rows change (the column merging then hardcodes the values). How would I do a GroupBy function but concatenate rather than sum/count/etc?

NOTE: It's worth noting that the text must stay as a Text type. The prices are sometimes $275pp or something and I need to maintain the letters

A visual of what I am trying to do is below:
[image]

Comment: Check out https://www.edureka.co/community/39337/how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values-in-powerquery and https://radacad.com/pre-concatenate-list-of-values-in-power-bi-using-power-query

Comment: Similar question: [Power Query - Group By, Text Combine List Distinct & Concatenate Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841989/power-query-group-by-text-combine-list-distinct-concatenate-text)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `Group by` Group and do some manipulations to add the quotation marks and brackets:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Price", type text}, {"Group", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "quotPrice", each """" & [Price] & """"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Group"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Price=text, Group=number, quotPrice=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"quotPrice")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Text", each "[" & [Custom] & "]"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Grouped", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is to combine a [`Table.Group()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-group) function with a [`Text.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-combine) function.

This will work for you:

```fs
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUjEyN1XSUTJUitUBcowNDBAcQyOQjBGEYwSWgXIMzZFkLMEyxkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Price = _t, Group = _t]),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"Count", each "[""" & Text.Combine([Price], """, """) & """]", type text}})
in
  #"Grouped rows"
```

[image]