# Power Query - Group By, Text Combine List Distinct & Concatenate Text

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm new to Power Query in Excel and want to apply a number of different functions to be able to achieve my target table, but I'm not sure on the syntax of how to bring this together..

I want to go from this...

[image]

to this..

[image]

I started by using the following steps;

- Select input table range (entire blue dataset)
- Select Transform
- Select Group By -> pooled ID, and also Target
- I then update the formula as per the screenshot and formula below but for one of the columns, the value returned is 'Error', as shown in the screenshot, and can't think why.. When I open the error it shows:

**Expression.Error: The column 'single ID' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
single ID**

[image]

Formula as text...

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"pooled ID", "Target"}, {
     {"Targets Combined", each Text.Combine([Target], "; "), type text}, 
     {"Single IDs Combined", each Text.Combine([single ID], "; "), type text}, 
     {"single ID Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

**I also want to introduce the final column and rename the headers as per the green example but I get an error when changing the headers.**

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: Formula as text...

= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"pooled  ID", "Target"},  {{"Targets Combined", each Text.Combine([Target], "; "), type text}, {"Single IDs Combined", each Text.Combine([Single], "; "), type text}, {"single ID Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})

Comment: Edit your question to show your entire M code as text. Very hard to read in the comments. Also, select one of the errors and post what the error is.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the text. The 'error' appears as a value in the table.

Comment: Ash_23S has the complete and right answer.  Just check his Upper/lower case against your column name

Comment: I hope I've made it clearer

Comment: Your formula as pasted is correct and gives the desired result (with no error).  Your formula in the screenshot, that shows the error, is wrong, however:  `...{"Single IDs Combined", each Text.Combine([single ID], "; "), type text}, ...`  But in the screenshot you show **[Single]** instead of **[single ID]**

Comment: Unable to comment on the name change line as you did not include that code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i've updated the query and it seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

There are two small errors in your code:

1. You used the column name `[Single]` when it should have been `[single ID]`:
   [image]
2. You didn't need to group by `"Target"` as well:
   [image]

When I change your code like this, it should produce the desired result:

```fs
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKsjPz1EwVNJRCkksSk8tUXAEMosz89JzUoHMWB28CpwIKXBGKDBCKHBCKHAhpMAVocAYocAZocANocAEocAFocCdkAIPpdhYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"pooled ID" = _t, Target = _t, #"single ID" = _t]),
  Types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"pooled ID", type text}, {"Target", type text}, {"single ID", type text}}),
  Grouped = Table.Group(
    Types, 
    {"pooled ID"}, 
    {
      {"Target", each Text.Combine([Target], "; "), type text}, 
      {"single ID", each Text.Combine([single ID], "; "), type text}, 
      {"single ID Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}
    }
  ),
  UniqueTarget = Table.AddColumn(Grouped, "Unique Target", each List.First(List.Distinct(Text.Split([Target], "; "))), type text)
in
  UniqueTarget
```

[image]